# mysql, how to select tree without node

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure this is a simple task, but I got stuck  for couple of days: I've got simplified table:

```
INSERT INTO `tree` (`fruit`, `tree`) VALUES
('apple',   'A'),
('pear',    'A'),
('apple',   'B'),
('banana',  'B');
```

and for example I need specify exactly what fruit i need and what i dont need, so I something like:

```
IN ('apple', 'banana') && NOT IN('pear')
```

should return "B" because we have got tree with apple and banana, without pear

Any ideas? thank you.

Comment: As i read you question, you want result A and B, yes?

Comment: I need only B (tree without pears)

Comment: @smidhonza Should I understand that you may want to specify "must have" "shouldn't have" sets? Or the first set us "can have"?

Comment: I need specify exactly which fruits the tree must have and what cannot have. I did not realize that it isn't so clear from my question, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use grouping and check aggregate values in a HAVING clause, like this:

```
SELECT   tree
FROM     tree
GROUP BY tree
HAVING   MAX(fruit IN ('apple', 'banana')) = 1
   AND   MAX(fruit IN ('pear')           ) = 0
;
```

A more platform-independent version of the same method would involve CASEs:

```
SELECT   tree
FROM     tree
GROUP BY tree
HAVING   MAX(CASE WHEN fruit IN ('apple', 'banana') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
   AND   MAX(CASE WHEN fruit IN ('pear')            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
;
```

To specify that the tree must have both `apple` and `banana`, add one more condition:

```
AND COUNT(*) = 2
```

If a tree is allowed to have duplicate fruit entries, use this condition instead:

```
AND COUNT(DISTINCT fruit) = 2
```

Alternatively you could specify separate conditions for each allowed fruit, like this:

```
SELECT   tree
FROM     tree
GROUP BY tree
HAVING   MAX(fruit = 'apple'  ) = 1
   AND   MAX(fruit = 'banana' ) = 1
   AND   MAX(fruit IN ('pear')) = 0
;
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple select should work with a NOT EXISTS check.

```
SELECT t1.tree FROM tree t1 WHERE t1.fruit='apple' 
AND NOT EXISTS 
           (SELECT 1 
            FROM tree t2 
             WHERE t1.tree=t2.tree and t2.fruit='pear');
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want only 'B' in your sample :

```
select t.fruit, t.tree
from tree t
where t.fruit = 'apple'
and not exists (select null
                  from tree t1
                  where t1.tree = t.tree
                  and t.fruit = 'pear');
```

so if you have

```
INSERT INTO `tree` (`fruit`, `tree`) VALUES
('apple',   'A'),
('pear',    'A'),
('apple',   'B')
('banana', 'B')
```

you will get only line `apple-B`

if you wanna extend your sample, and get all trees that have at least 1 time apple and no pear, but also banana, for example

```
select t.fruit, t.tree
from tree t
where not exists (select null
                      from tree t1
                      where t1.tree = t.tree
                      and t.fruit = 'pear')
and exists        (select null
                      from tree t1
                      where t1.tree = t.tree
                      and t.fruit = 'apple');
```

then you'll get `apple-B` and `banana-B`

Answer (score 2):

Although preivous answers are perfectly right, I think you can try a SQL without nested SQLs using LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT A.tree FROM
    tree A LEFT JOIN tree B
ON
    A.tree = B.tree AND
    B.fruit = 'pear' 
WHERE 
    B.fruit IS NULL AND
    A.fruit = 'apple';
```

The ON condition will make all B.* fields be NULL for any combination of `tree`table inner cartesian product where 'tree' columns do not match or the second fruit isn't a pear. The WHERE condition will filter the result to contain only those trees for which the second group is null and whose fruit is apple.

Combining both conditions you get: All those trees with apples but without pears.

**EDIT:** (after your question edit)

Whenever you no have repeated tree-fruit pairs, you can try:

```
SELECT A.tree FROM
    tree A LEFT JOIN tree B
ON
    A.tree = B.tree AND
    B.fruit IN ('pear') #Can't have
WHERE 
    B.fruit IS NULL AND
    A.fruit IN ('apple','banana') # Must have           <---\
GROUP BY A.tree HAVING COUNT(1) = 2; #Number of elements in /
```

Comment: @smidhonza It would be easier and cleaner if "must have" set were "can have" since you can remove the `GROUP BY HAVING COUNT` trick which I don't like very much. You have another option which is to nest my first query into another but I don't like it neither